# Floating Action Button: The following classes not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When i try to create FloatingActionButton I get the error: 
The following classes not be instantiated.
Exception details:
`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080054 type #0x0 is not valid`

xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id = "@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
}
```

what's the problem?

Comment: move this `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` to the top of your build.gradle, see if that works all else looks okay to me, i haven't worked with realm but in Android studio your plugins should not be applied in the dependencies section furthermore see this example https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/newsreaderExample/build.gradle

Comment: is this an issue with the preview or does your application actually crash?

Comment: this is rendering problem

Comment: when i run the application fab without icon

Comment: can you share the code where you get a reference to this FloatingActionButton using findViewById()

Comment: I solved the problem. had to change the version of the support library on 23.3.0. thank you:)